# How do I create div that can be dragged up to reveal content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I have a div with an image and some text. I want the whole div to be draggable, but only upwards. When the visitor drags the div upwards with their mouse, there is content under the div, that doesn't move. That means that that content is already there. The draggable div is overlapping it. A good example of what I want to do is the Microsoft Windows 8 lock-screen. You drag up, and the login screen is under it. Thanks!

Comment: Try jQuery + jQueryUI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ there you have some examples that are almost exactly to what you are asking

Comment: You asked the exact same question a few minutes ago, and it got closed. [How to create div that can be dragged up to reveal content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10015594/how-to-create-div-that-can-be-dragged-up-to-reveal-content)

Comment: yes, but it got closed while i was editing it and fixing it. it wasn't a question when i first wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something *very* similar to your problem not a while ago. If you want an element which can be dragged up use the `axis` option in the `draggable()` tool in jQuery UI. You would need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").draggable({
        axis: "y"
    });
});
```

This defines it as draggable, and only on the Y-axis (vertical).

Comment: WOAH! I just realized this is from April 4th. Lol XD

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use jQuery UI's draggable feature.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: That lets the div be dragged around anywhere. I want the div to fill the screen. Then it can be dragged UP out of the screen.